# Is it possible to use a partitionless EBS image as an HVM AMI?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-ami

Attempting to locate/create an EC2 AMI that meets my current needs. HVM is preferred over PV, because the newer and larger EC2 instance types only support HVM (we're targeting r3.4xlarge) and a partitionless "whole drive" image is preferred over one with a real partition table because it's nice to be able to dynamically enlarge the file system without having to mess with the partition table on the boot drive.

Is this even possible, or does the HVM boot system fundamentally require an actual partition table? So far all of my attempts to create a working HVM AMI using a whole drive image have failed to boot with no visible error.

Comment: I don't think you can boot a real machine "partitionless" either, without some very strange magic. Anyway, editing the partition table is trivial, so that really shouldn't be a limiting factor.

Comment: Editing the partition table requires taking the instance offline, detaching the root volume, attaching it to a second instance, doing the actual partition changes in parted, detaching the volume from the second instance, reattaching it to the first instance, and booting the original instance again. Correct me if this is wrong. This is not a dealbreaker, but it would be great to avoid this process the way we've been doing with our PV instances.

Comment: That is wrong. You can edit it online and then simply reboot the instance.

Comment: I'm curious about how this would work. Do you have any further documentation I can refer to? The official AWS docs (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/storage_expand_partition.html) state that "You cannot perform the rest of this procedure on a running instance" and my preliminary attempt to modify the partition table with parted gives the error "Error: Partition /dev/xvda1 is being used. You must unmount it before you modify it with Parted."

Comment: What about [growpart](https://apps.fedoraproject.org/packages/cloud-utils-growpart)?

Comment: if you use a separate data volume and leave the system volume as it is you can make this a non-issue.  then i attach a data volume to `/dev/sdX` and test for existance of `/dev/xvdX1`.